# Is set theory a part of, or even identical to, mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory

The philosopher Quine famously said that second-order logic is set theory in sheep's clothing. However, what if it is really the other way around? Is set theory part of mathematical logic, or even the same thing as mathematical logic? I am not talking merely about first-order logic, but second(and higher)-order logic. Perhaps set theory is the same thing as higher-order logic. So, has any philosopher argued for this point of view, and if so, can I see some of their papers?

Comment: No, the axioms of set theory are not logical truth: they are mathematical axioms.

Comment: See [SEP, Logicism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism/):"Logicism is a philosophical, foundational, and foundationalist doctrine that can be advanced with respect to any branch of mathematics...The strong version of logicism maintains that all mathematical truths in the chosen branch(es) form a species of logical truth." After Gödel the strong form of logicism, as applied to all of mathematics, is considered non-viable, but some weaker partial versions are still defended.

Comment: An interesting approach to set theory is Penelope Maddy, [Defending the Axioms: On the Philosophical Foundations of Set Theory (Oxford UPy, 2011)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Defending_the_Axioms/FtoUDAAAQBAJ).

Comment: Math logic is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The Handbook of Mathematical Logic (ed. John Barwise, 1977) divides mathematical logic into four parts: model theory, set theory, recursion theory and proof theory. But it makes sense to ask whether this is just a convenience or whether there is a more principled distinction. To some extent, the answer will depend on how broad is your definition of 'logic'. It may also depend on your preferred approach to the philosophy of mathematics, e.g. whether you are a platonist, formalist, logicist, intuitionist, or something else.

To a [logicist](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logicism/) all of mathematics is reducible to logic, so set theory and all other branches of mathematics would qualify. Logicism is not popular today. It is widely considered to have been busted by Gödel's incompleteness results, among other considerations, though there are some neo-logicists who defend a weaker version of the idea.

An approach more in tune with a formalist understanding of mathematics is to distinguish between logic and theory. A formal logic contains a proof system that will include axioms and/or rules specifying how formulas are derived from other formulas. A logic contains logical symbols that have a fixed meaning. In the case of classical propositional logic, these symbols include the familiar connectives, negation, conjunction, disjunction, etc.

A theory is set of sentences, which are formulas with no free variables. The non-logical symbols that feature in the theory do not have a meaning that is fixed in the same way that the logical constants are. The non-logical symbols are subject to *interpretation* in the technical sense in which that term is used within [model theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/). Together, the logical and non-logical symbols are used to define a formal language.

On this approach, it would make sense to say that set theory is a theory and not part of logic. Set theory introduces the set membership predicate ∊ and this has a standard interpretation within set theory. But it is a non-logical constant, and it would form part of the signature of the formal language.

A further consideration in favour of treating set theory as theory is that theories are usually, though not always, closed under a logical consequence relation. Set theory requires an underlying logic. The most common choice is classical logic, though others can be used, which is why there is constructive set theory, based on intuitionistic logic, and paraconsistent set theory, which is based on logics without explosion, and others.

Another point is that if you were to include set theory as part of logic, why not include [mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/) as well, since it is similar in many ways? It seems more appropriate to treat such subjects as theories, albeit ones with a very general degree of applicability.

It remains true that other branches of mathematics can be expressed in set theory, and so one could say are reducible to set theory. But this is not a unique feature of set theory. The foundations of mathematics can also be expressed using type theory or category theory, for example.

So, on the whole, it is doubtful whether one should identify mathematical logic with set theory, or even to treat set theory as part of logic.

Comment: I agree - set theory can be expressed in a formal logic, but is distinct.